# How to install google repo on mac

Tags: git, macos, github, repo

I just got a new mac like two weeks back.
I am trying to install Google Repo

I am not into android development but my company uses this repo to store its codebase.

do I still need to carry out all the instructions from `Establishing a Build Environment` tab? It asks to create a partition etc.

also after downloading repo into ~/bin/repo what am I supposed to do? I mean how to install that file. The website has given few SHA keys but I don't know how to use them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/ is a good place to start. Read through it carefully: there are links to how to use SHA keys, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer to use brew

```
brew install repo
```

Comment: Lol in what way doesn't this aswer the question of how to install repo on macos? This should be the accepted answer it works and is the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

You already have git installed (as part os OSX)

- Open terminal
- got to the desired directory
- clone the project:
  Get a local copy of the repo repository with this command from either mirror location:

  ```
  git clone https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo
  # OR:
  git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
  ```

> also after downloading repo into ~/bin/repo what am I supposed to do?
>   I mean how to install that file.
>   The website has given few SHA keys but I don't know how to use them.

Follow those instructions:
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#installing-repo

---

What does those SHA-1 means?

```
For version 1.17, the SHA-1 checksum for repo is ddd79b6d5a7807e911b524cb223bc3544b661c28
For version 1.19, the SHA-1 checksum for repo is 92cbad8c880f697b58ed83e348d06619f8098e6c
For version 1.20, the SHA-1 checksum for repo is e197cb48ff4ddda4d11f23940d316e323b29671c
For version 1.21, the SHA-1 checksum for repo is b8bd1804f432ecf1bab730949c82b93b0fc5fede
For version 1.22, the SHA-1 checksum for repo is da0514e484f74648a890c0467d61ca415379f791
```

Those are the SHA-1 you have to checkout according to your version.

---

#### How to it?

Read here about the checkout part and do it:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset-old-commit/34519716#34519716)

Answer (score 0):

> The website has given few SHA keys but I don't know how to use them.

The SHA-1 keys are for verifying the `repo` download.

```
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ openssl sha1 ~/bin/repo
SHA1(~/bin/repo)= da0514e484f74648a890c0467d61ca415379f791
```

From http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#installing-repo

> For version 1.22, the SHA-1 checksum for repo is da0514e484f74648a890c0467d61ca415379f791